# C# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

Tags: c#

## Quem puder me ajudar e me explicar este problema ficarei agradecido

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BuscaLargura
{
   partial class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            /* Node grafos = Grafo();
             Console.WriteLine(" ");
             bfs_transversal(grafos);*/
            List<Node> listanos = new List<Node>();
            List<Node> conectados = new List<Node>();
            String[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Pedro Pacheco\Desktop\Mapa.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                if (text[i].Contains("city"))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(text[i][5]);
                    listanos.Add(new Node(text[i][5]));//adiciona um Nó com o nome da 5 posição da linha do Mapa.txt
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                if (text[i].Contains("route"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(text[i][6]);
                    for (int nopai = 0; nopai < listanos.Count; nopai++)//varrendo os nós sem conexão
                    {
                        if (listanos[nopai].data == text[i][6])//verificando se o Nó.data é igual a  text[i][6] ( exemplo= route=A)
                        {
                            for (int nofilho = 0; nofilho < listanos.Count; nofilho++)
                            {                                
                                if (listanos[nofilho].data == text[i][8])
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(text[i][8]);
                                    //listanos[nopai].conectados.Add(new Node(listanos[nofilho]));
                                    conectados.Add(listanos[nofilho]);
                                }

                            }
                                listanos[nopai].conectados.AddRange(conectados);  
                                conectados.Clear();
                        }                      
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

## Classe Node:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BuscaLargura { 

  public class Node { 

    public List<Node> conectados; 

    public char data;

    public Node(char data,List<Node> conectados)
    {
        this.conectados = conectados;
        this.data = data;
    }
    public Node(char data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public Node (List<Node> filhos)
    {
        this.conectados.AddRange(filhos);
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Erro]

Comment: Sem a definição da classe `Node` fica difícil de ajudar-lhe. Se decidir publicar a classe node, marque meu nome(com arroba) para que eu possa ser notificado. Daí te dou uma força.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Pronto

Comment: Minha intenção é após eu criar essa listanos, para cada um dessa lista atribuir a outra lista de conectados

Comment: public List conectados; você mandou ali em baixo: `public List conectados; ` não seria `public List<Node> conectados;`?

Comment: Deu erro pois não encontrou `Mapa.txt`????

Comment: o Mapa esta lendo perfeitamente

Comment: O meu aqui, é não funciona pois eu não tenho esse arquivo. Eu preciso dele

Comment: aonde posso disponibilizar esse Mapa ?

Comment: Edita o post e passa ou um link dele num sistema de arquivo online(tipo github) ou se for curto coloca na própria edição.

Comment: Ou então passa só um fragmento dele que funcione e gere o mesmo erro que está dando ai com você.

Comment: Postei o Mapa @AugustoVasques mas esta dividido por linhas

Comment: Agr tenho uma duvida preciso separar a string -> route=A-C;140;  e pegar somente o 140

Comment: [`String[] String.Split(char c)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___)

Answer (score 1):

## Qual o problema?

O problema é que o campo `public List<Node> conectados;` não está sendo inicializado junto do objeto `Node`.

Seu programa faz todos os cálculo de rota mas na hora de passa os resultados ele encontra um `null` no lugar da lista `conectados`.

## Porque isso está acontecendo?

Apesar de você ter três constructors para classe `Node` apenas dois fazem a inicialização do campo `public List<Node> conectados;` e justamente o único constructor que você usa no código é o constructor que não inicializa o campo `conectados`.

## Solução:

Há duas duas soluções para seu problema:

1 Dentro da classe `Node` no constructor cujo a assinatura é `public Node(char data)` faça a seguinte mudança:

```
        public Node(char data){
            this.data = data;

            //Adicione está linha para corrigir o problema.
            this.conectados = new List<Node>();
        }
```

2 Outra solução seria trocar, dentro da função `Main()`, o construtor usado no seu programa o que ficaria assim:

```
      for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
           {
                if (text[i].Contains("city"))
                {
                    // Essa era a linha antiga:
                    // listanos.Add(new Node(text[i][5]));
                    // que substitui por essa:
                    listanos.Add(new Node(text[i][5], new List<Node>()));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado !!! faz todo o sentido !

Comment: Quando quiser marcar uma pergunta como resolvida escolha uma resposta que considere correta e ao lado esquerdo dela abaixo da pontuação tem um simbolo(✔). Clique nele que indica que a questão foi resolvida. Leia [O que devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Não é uma resposta directa à pergunta, mas com linq pode simplificar seu codigo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Pedro Pacheco\Desktop\Mapa.txt");

    var result = text.Where(x => x.Contains("route"))
        .GroupBy(y => y[6])
        .Select(z => new Node(z.Key, z.Select(nf => new Node(nf[8])).ToList()))
        .ToList();

    // Adiciona existentes em "city" que não existem em "route" (neste caso 'H')
    result.AddRange(text.Where(x => x.Contains("city") && !result.Any(y => y.data == x[5])).Select(x => new Node(x[5])));

    // Ordena pelos nodes pai
    result = result.OrderBy(x => x.data).ToList();

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public class Node
{
    public List<Node> conectados;

    public char data;

    public Node(char data, List<Node> conectados)
    {
        this.conectados = conectados;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node(char data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Gostei desse código ficou bem claro.

Answer (score -2):

```
city=A(100,80);
city=B(160,70);
city=C(110,50);
city=D(140,120);
city=F(155,40);
city=G(210,60);
city=H(190,10);
city=I(170,110);
route=A-C;140;
route=A-D;155;
route=C-F;125;
route=D-B;115;
route=D-I;152;
route=B-F;119;
route=B-G;136;
route=G-F;133;
route=F-H;163;
route=I-H;197;
```

Comment: vc não está a instancia a `public List<Node> conectados` dentro da classe node... ficaria  `public List<Node> conectados = new List<Node>();` mas edite a pergunta e coloque um exemplo do que quer que contenha as listas

Comment: é bem simples oque eu quero, veja que na classe Node tem public char e um public List<Node> 
previamente eu cadastro  numa lista todos os Nós com somente o char atribuido, e posteriormente gostaria de acessar esses Nós sem os nós filhos e atribuindo, conforme o Mapa diz